# How do I add javascript code into reactJS file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to reactjs and javascript in general, and I'm trying to figure out how to get this simple js code to work in my reactjs file. I want the text to turn red onClick.

I have tried: Creating an external js file and importing it using [Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to insert a  tag

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './about.css';
import logo from './S54 Logo 2.svg';
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import aboutJS from './about';

export default class About extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="about-page">
                <Helmet>
                    <script>
                        {'aboutJS'};
                    </script>
                </Helmet>
                <img id="about-page-logo-img" src={logo} />
                <h2 id="mission-statement" onclick="myFunction()">
                    Catalog the World's Underrepresented Art so everyone can share in the enjoyable experience
                </h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

this was the js file

```
export function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mission-statement").style.color = "red";
}
```

Ive also tried adding that js code straight into the script tag, instead of importing the file but that didn't work.

I tried putting a  tag for that external js file I created into the  of [my index.html file](https://ibb.co/dJBqf29), and calling the function in my reactjs file.

Nothing is working. Where and how should I add this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zelmi, You can `import { myFunction } from 'path/to/your/jsfile.js'` which allows you to use `myFunction` any where in your JS file where your component lives.

Also, use `onClick` instead of `onclick`, wrap your function with Carely Braces `{}` instead of Quotes `""`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './about.css';
import logo from './S54 Logo 2.svg';
import { myFunction } from 'path/to/your/jsfile.js'; //HERE
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import aboutJS from './about';

export default class About extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="about-page">
                <Helmet>
                    <script>
                        {'aboutJS'};
                    </script>
                </Helmet>
                <img id="about-page-logo-img" src={logo} />
                <h2 id="mission-statement" onClick={myFunction}>
                    Catalog the World's Underrepresented Art so everyone can share in the enjoyable experience
                </h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked and is very simple

Comment: Remember to remove the `Helmet` from your component and your `packages`. I am glad, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In JSX, props use this syntax: `propName={...}` with strings being an exception, where you can do `propName="..."`.

So you should just be able to do `onClick={myFunction}`

Edit: you might have to do `onClick={myFunction.bind(this)}` to get your desired effect.

Edit: fixed Camel Case

Comment: Slight correction: event handlers in React use CamelCase, so it should be `onClick`

Answer (score 1):

Zelmi, React uses JSX, which means Javascript XML. You can write JS directly into the component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './about.css';
import logo from './S54 Logo 2.svg';
import aboutJS from './about';

export default class About extends Component {

    myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("mission-statement").style.color = "red";
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="about-page">
                <Helmet>
                    <script>
                        {'aboutJS'};
                    </script>
                </Helmet>
                <img id="about-page-logo-img" src={logo} />
                <h2 id="mission-statement" onclick="myFunction()">
                    Catalog the World's Underrepresented Art so everyone can share in the enjoyable experience
                </h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And thus call the `myFunction` from anywhere in the page.

You also need to understand how React and the VirtualDOM work, [start by reading the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

React does not work with the standard html `onclick` attribute but rather with the React prop `onClick`, which takes in a function as well, but you need to show React XML that you are calling your JS code by opening a `{}` code scope like so:

```
        <div id="about-page">
                    <Helmet>
                        <script>
                            {'aboutJS'};
                        </script>
                    </Helmet>
                    <img id="about-page-logo-img" src={logo} />
                    <h2 id="mission-statement" onClick={this.myFunction}>
                        Catalog the World's Underrepresented Art so everyone can share in the enjoyable experience
                    </h2>
                </div>
```

**EDIT**

You also unfortunately need to bind your function when using React Class component, in the constructor method:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Part of the point of React is to abstract away the DOM so you don't have to do things like `getElementById` and all that.

A simple way to accomplish what you want to do would be something like this:

```
export default class About extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            color: "black"
        }
    }
    myFunction = () => {
        this.setState({color: "red"});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="about-page">
                <img id="about-page-logo-img" src={logo} />
                <h2 onClick={this.myFunction} style={{color: this.state.color}}>
                    Catalog the World's Underrepresented Art so everyone can share in the enjoyable experience
                </h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Note that if your setup doesn't allow arrow functions in class properties, you may have to bind `this` to the function like so:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            color: "black"
        }
        this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
    }
```